# Is the divergence of a gradient field the trace of the Hessian?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given a $C^2$ multivariate function $f : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$, the gradient defines a vector field, the divergence of this vector field, then, should be the trace of the Hessian matrix, right?  I'm not entirely sure because the simplified version of divergence is only ever given for $d=3$.

Comment: Yes.  This is also known as the (flat) Laplacian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, evidently, according to @user72694 above, this is known as the "flat" Laplacian